# Passing dynamic string in hyperlink as parameter in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to pass a dynamic string builder variable in jsp I am generating a string through code. String Builder variable has some value but i am not able to pass it in at run time.It doesn't get the value.
**CODE FOR VARIABLE**

```
<% 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    if (request.getAttribute("Brand") != null) {
        String Brand[] = (String[]) request.getAttribute("Brand");
        for (String brand : Brand) {
            sb.append("Brand=");
            sb.append(brand);
            sb.append("&");
        }
    }
    if (request.getAttribute("Flavour") != null) {
        String Flavour[] = (String[]) request.getAttribute("Flavour");
        for (String flavour : Flavour) {
            sb.append(flavour);
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.trimToSize();
        pageContext.setAttribute("sb", sb);
    }
    out.print("this is string" + sb);
%>
```

**CODE FOR HYPERLINK**

```
<a href="Filter_Products?${sb}page=${currentPage + 1}" style="color: white;text-decoration: none;">Next</a></td>
```

Comment: what is the output of the last line in your code? What is the html code of the hyperlink that you get?

Comment: <a href="Filter_Products?page=2">

Comment: and what is the output of `out.print("this is string" + sb);` ?

Comment: this is stringBrand=optimum nutrition&&Brand=ultimate nutrition&&Brand=muscle blaze&&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to add sb to the pageContext, request, session or context scope to be able to access it through an EL expression - it will not pick up variables declared only in scriptlets. Modify as follows so that that sb is ***always*** put into the pageContext:

```
if (request.getAttribute("Flavour") != null) {
        String[] flavours = (String[]) request.getAttribute("Flavour");
        for (String flavour : flavours) {
            sb.append(flavour);
            sb.append("&");
        }
        sb.trimToSize();

    }
    pageContext.setAttribute("sb", sb);
```

I have also suggested a change to improve the clarity of your code when assigning the array of 'flavour' String values.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting the value to pageContext and trying to accessed via ${}. This by default refer to request scope. Try ${pageScope.sb}

Apart from that Your code looks fine, but i'm confused with the &&. Usually the URL parameter are separated by just one & symbol. Why do you need 2?

Comment: i tried but still not be able to get the value of sb

Comment: Sorry. My bad. `sb` is just fine. Anyway what error do you get? When you try to view the page source what value do you get for the hyperlink?

Comment: sorry not able to print value of sb when i write like ${sb}

Comment: isnt this best suits in comment section?

Comment: So does that come as empty? Or do you get any error? Does the out.print() writes some value?

Comment: @JqueryLearner : Yes it is. I just started with an answer, but then found that answer was not relevant. So instead of deleting I just modified. :(

Comment: out.print() works fine but when i try to access like ${sb} it doesn't print the value

Comment: Updated answer. Did you try ${pageScope.sb}